# WIFI network problem

Tags: system

when logging  into v14.04this msg appears

Authentication required by wifi network

What is this?  I have tried by network wpa key to no avail

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the information requested by Pilot6.  It will also be helpful to post the output of 'iwconfig'.  The more information you include the better your chances of getting the help you need.

Answer (score 0):

You try to connect automatically to a network that is secured by a password, so you need authentication. Since you see this message either you did not enter the password at all in your networkmanager or you did enter a wrong one.